# When does infinite intersection preserve a closed property?

Tags: soft-question, convex-analysis, intuition, regular-language

There are two statements well known in Math and Computer Science:

1. Intersection of **infinite** number of regular languages **is not** regular.
2. Intersection of **infinite** number of convex sets **is** convex.

Notice that in both cases, a finite intersection preserves the corresponding property:

1. Intersection of **finite** number of regular languages **is**  regular.
2. Intersection of **finite** number of convex sets **is** convex.

I.e, both regular languages and convex sets are closed under intersection.

In most literature the fact about infinite intersection of convex sets is treated as obvious and not requiring any proofs. Before I learnt the things about regular languages, I would conclude the same about them.
What is so special about regular languages which leads us to a different conclusion?
Why is it everybody relies on the intuition in the case with convex sets and why it does not work for regular languages?

Comment: what does a regular language have to do with a convex set?

Comment: Nothing. Both of them are sets having some property. I'm just demonstrating the point, that sometimes when we do an infinite intersection we are loosing the property of a set (which wouldn't be lost if the intersection is finite), and sometimes not. There should be something special about the property.

Comment: Well, yes. This is the nature of the definition. Perhaps this has to do with some sort of "compactness" - See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactness_theorem

Answer (score 1):

*What is so special about regular languages which leads us to a different conclusion?*

Well, the set of all regular languages contains the singletons and is closed under finite union (by definition) and under complement (a consequence of Kleene's theorem). It is also known that there are some non-regular languages. Now take **any** set of subsets of an infinite set $E$ containing the singletons, closed under finite union and complement and not equal to $\mathcal{P} (E)$. Then this set of subsets will not be closed under infinite intersection.